# ModelForm won't create instance of model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a frontend form in my Django site that will allow users to add entries to my SQL database.

**But when I use the form nothing happens in my database. What am I doing wrong?**

I thought the right way would be to use the ModelForm technique.

My models looks like this:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    wage = models.IntegerField(default=3100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So I wrote this in my *forms.py*:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Actor

class ActorForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Actor
        fields = ['name', 'wage']
form = ActorForm()
```

I then added this to my *views.py*:

```
def get_actor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/scenes/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ActorForm()

    return render(request, 'scenes/actor.html', {'form': form})

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'scenes/thanks.html',)
```

And this in a template called *actors.html*

```
<form action="/scenes/actor/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: also no point instantiating the form in forms.py - get rid of this line ```form = ActorForm()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the model form's [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method after checking that it's valid:

```
def get_actor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/scenes/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ActorForm()

    return render(request, 'scenes/actor.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I was certain that I read that ModelForm had the save() function built in. Thanks so much!